# DbSet.Attach, what exactly does it do?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Follow the methods below:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
     DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Repository
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext();

    public User Attach1(User entity)
    {
        var ent = db.Entry<User>(entity);
        ent.State = EntityState.Modified;
        if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
            return ent.Entity;
        return null;
    }

    public User Attach2(User entity)
    {
        return db.Users.Attach(entity);
    }

}
```

**Is there any difference between `Attach1` and `Attach2`?**

Comment: please post code that compiles

Comment: See again, do not put it because the code is simple.

Comment: What I mean is your `Attach1` and `Attach2` methods are syntactically incorrect/incomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Attach1` and `Attach2` methods perform different things and it is not clear what you expect to do in these methods. When you attach an entity to EF it will be added to the context in `Unchanged` state. If you modify the entity after attaching, then EF will track those changes and the entity will be in `Modified` state.

**Attach1**

This method will attach an entity and mark it as modified. So the subsequent `SaveChanges()` will update all the properties of the entity. Calling `SaveChanges()` inside the `Attach` method is not recommended since it does more than attaching.

**Attach2**

This method will attach the entity as `Unchanged`.

Comment: The goal is to update an object.
I use the Attach to update properties in the database.